# Backhandler.removeeventlistener is invalid when using componentWillUnmount

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Why is BackHandler.removeEventListener invalid when using componentWillUnmount ?

```
componentWillUnmount(): void {
    console.log(1112223)
    BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", () => {
        console.log(2222222222)
    });
    console.log(3333333)
 }
```

The last conslog will output，But the method in the second conslog, callback, did not execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter is not a callback. It is the handler that you registered

```
componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
}

componentWillUmmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
}

handleBackPress = () => {
    // Handle your back press
}
```

Or you could use the result from `BackHandler.addEventListener` to unsubcribe it.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubcribe = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
}

componentWillUmmount() {
    this.unsubcribe();
}
```